# In Java why would I be unable to import a sub-class into another class when I can import the superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, import

I am building a small scale system that has both workers and managers, manager inherits all of the workers properties because he also is a worker but has higher access within the system. I have a system class which has been reduced in size for clarity,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class system {
    static Depot depot = new Depot("d1");
    //static Depot depot2 = new Depot("d2");
    //static Depot depot3 = new Depot("d3");

    static ArrayList<Depot> depotArray = new ArrayList<Depot>();

    public static void systemSetup() {
        depotArray.add(depot);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        StateThreadClass stateThreadClass = new StateThreadClass();
        Thread thread = new Thread(stateThreadClass);
        thread.start();     
        systemSetup();
        GetDepot();
    }
  }
```

Once I get a depot it brings me to my main depot class which holds most calculations.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

//import Driver.Manager;

public class Depot{     
    String name;
    int LOCount = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Long date3 = 1478217600000L;
    Date date1 = new Date(1478217600000L);
    Date date2 = new Date(1479217600000L);  
    Worker worker = new Worker ("tom", "tom", false);
    Worker worker = new Worker ("phil2", "phil2", false);
    Worker worker = new Worker ("phil", "phil", true);
  ----->  Manager manager = new Manager("ben", "ben", true);
    etc.....
 }
```

I can instantiate the Worker with no problem and use it within the system but when I attempt to instantiate the Manager I get an error saying "Manager cannot be resolved to a type", I am given the option of importing it. When I do I get another error "The import Worker cannot be resolved"

This is my Worker and Manager class minus unnecessary code,

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Worker {    
private String username; 
private String password; 
private boolean available;

public Worker(String username, String password, boolean av) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.available = av;
}

public Boolean CheckPassword(String password) {         
    return this.password.equals(password);
}   

public Boolean CheckUsername(String username) {         
    return this.username.equals(username);
}               

public class Manager extends Worker {           
    public Manager(String username, String password, boolean av) {
        super(username, password,av);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I know I shouldn't be using static but I will deal with that another day! 
cheers

Comment: I believe you mean `public class Manager extends Worker` and not extends `Driver`

Comment: It's good to leave out unnecessary code, but the code you leave in has to still make sense. Is `Manager` supposed to be an inner class of `Worker`, or did you just leave out the bottom of the `Worker` class?

Comment: any reason why the Manager class is within the worker?

Comment: You're making some fundamental errors here in terms of your naming conventions and your imports. Don't call your main class system (too close to System and classes should begin with a capital letter according to Java coding standards). I suspect that your Manager class should be subclassing Worker, rather than Driver. Then you simply need to include the import that refers to your Manager class' package declaration accordingly.

Comment: driver is only in here by mistake from editing for this post. It is Worker in my code.

Comment: It is showing as a private class within Worker also. Is that another textual error here? You'll need to be super clear when posting your code in your question given the nature of the question itself, as it pertains to getting to your Manager class correctly on the classpath.

Comment: @anon is `Manager` an inner class of `Worker` (i.e. declared inside Worker)?

Comment: Where is that sorry? worker is Public and I declared manager as public when I extended worker?

Comment: What is the package of your Manager class? And what is the package of your Depot class? If they don't exist in the same package, then you're going to have to add an import for your Manager class like `import qualified.path.to.managerpackage.Manager;`

Comment: yes worker is in a class of its own and then manager extends worker from inside Worker. Is that wrong then i take it?

Comment: Look at the code formatting in your Worker class. You need to indent it and close it properly. At the moment, the Manager class appears to be an inner class of Worker, which is probably wrong.

Comment: they do exist within the same package

Comment: Ensure that your Manager class is defined in its own file. And if they're in the same package, then you don't require any import. You'll be able to refer to Manager without any more issues. If that fixes it for you, I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: That has sorted it Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your Manager class is defined in its own file separately. As it's defined as an inner class of Worker, then it's currently not accessible outside of your Worker class.

Once you have that fixed, then you should be able to refer to your Manager class from your Depot class, provided they are in the same package. If they are not, then simply include the import for your Manager class and you'll be able to access your Manager class.

Some info on inner classes: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077411/core-java/inner-classes.html.